# Text as button with styled components

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components

I try to make a text as button with react native with styled components.

So I have this:

```
import { Button } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const ButtonCol = styled(Button)`
    backgroundcolor: red;
    color: white;
    border: 0;  
    
`;
```

and the component:

```
export const CategoryInfoCard = ({ category = {} }) => {
    const {
        name = "Zoogdieren",
        images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg",
        icon = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSE3_hmm2zWrH4ZLUoqEr4FUb5f-BIn9_c5Qg&usqp=CAU",
        detail = "Detail",
    } = category;

    return (
        <CategoryCard
            elevation={5}
            style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            }}>
            <Text variant="caption" style={{ left: 100 }}>
                {name}
            </Text>
            <CategoryGroupCardCover source={{ uri: images }} />
            <Card.Actions>
                <ButtonCol title="ok" variant="text" />
            </Card.Actions>

        </CategoryCard>
    );
};
```

But nothing changed. With this I mean I see a blue rectangele with oke in it.

Question: how to make text as a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add an `onPress` prop to your Text component:

```
<Text style={styles.titleText} onPress={()=>console.log('Text pressed!')}>
  {ok}
</Text>
```

More information here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text

Hope you find it helpful. Upvote is highly appreciated!

Comment: style={styles.titleText} is just an example!